# Which Package has net_tstamp.h?

Tags: linux, networking, c, centos-6

I attempted to compile the source code here:
http://os1a.cs.columbia.edu/lxr/source/Documentation/networking/timestamping/timestamping.c?a=x86;v=2.6.32

However, I got a compiler error:
error: linux/net_tstamp.h: No such file or directory

I looked at /usr/include/linux, and indeed I don't have that file.

Then, I searched online for awhile but I can't find which package has that file.

I am on CentOS 6.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is found in the linux-headers package. I believe that package is called kernel-devel on CentOS.